# ionic error with fullcalendar when build android

Tags: angularjs, ionic2, ionic3

[01:15:36]  typescript: ...r2-fullcalendar/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/interfaces/container.d.ts, line: 35 A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol.

```
  L35:   * This allows us to jump from a container to a sibling container or component
```

[01:15:36]  typescript: ...r2-fullcalendar/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/interfaces/container.d.ts, line: 40
      L36:   * view with the same parent, so we can remove listeners efficiently.

```
        A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol.

  L40:   * Queries active for this container - all the views inserted to / removed from
  L41:   * this container are reported to queries referenced here.
```

[01:15:36]  typescript: ...r2-fullcalendar/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/interfaces/container.d.ts, line: 45
[01:15:36]  typescript: ...r2-fullcalendar/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/interfaces/container.d.ts, line: 50
[01:15:36]  typescript: ...r2-fullcalendar/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/interfaces/container.d.ts, line: 58

Answer (score 3):

Add "skipLibCheck": true in "compilerOptions" of your tsconfig.json